# Spring boot vs grails 3

Tags: spring-boot, grails3

What's the major difference between spring boot and grails 3 framework?

Why is spring boot better than grails 3 framework?

Answer (score 8):

It cannot be said that spring boot is better then grails. Grails 3 is build on top of spring boot and it has a number of usefull features (for example gorm).

Here you can find more info from grails developers:

https://objectcomputing.com/news/2017/06/28/grails-vs-spring-boot